# Duplicate symbol - third party library Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios

I need your help to resolve this issue. I am importing a third party library under frameworks and started seeing this error. Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

```
Ld /Users/rsangili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ADTCommercial-cpvyllovxoojyngrlpxrjwdjxido/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ADTCommercial.app/ADTCommercial normal i386
    cd /Users/rsangili/Desktop/Personal/iPhone-xcodeproj
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/rsangili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ADTCommercial-cpvyllovxoojyngrlpxrjwdjxido/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/rsangili/Desktop/Personal/iPhone-xcodeproj/AMPSmartClient -L/Users/rsangili/Desktop/Personal/iPhone-xcodeproj/Custom/ADT_Resources/Soti_SDK -L/Users/rsangili/Desktop/Personal/iPhone-xcodeproj/Custom/BarcodeScanner/iphone/ZXingWidget/build/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/rsangili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ADTCommercial-cpvyllovxoojyngrlpxrjwdjxido/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/rsangili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ADTCommercial-cpvyllovxoojyngrlpxrjwdjxido/Build/Intermediates/ADTCommercial.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ADTCommercial.build/Objects-normal/i386/ADTCommercial.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lxml2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 /Users/rsangili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ADTCommercial-cpvyllovxoojyngrlpxrjwdjxido/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libZXingWidget.a -liconv -lstdc++ -lc++ -lxml2 -framework CoreTelephony -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -weak_framework AdSupport -lSOTIMCAgentSDK -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreData -framework QuartzCore -lz -framework CFNetwork -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -lAMPSmartClient -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/rsangili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ADTCommercial-cpvyllovxoojyngrlpxrjwdjxido/Build/Intermediates/ADTCommercial.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ADTCommercial.build/Objects-normal/i386/ADTCommercial_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/rsangili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ADTCommercial-cpvyllovxoojyngrlpxrjwdjxido/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ADTCommercial.app/ADTCommercial

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_KeychainItemWrapper.genericPasswordQuery in:
    /Users/rsangili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ADTCommercial-cpvyllovxoojyngrlpxrjwdjxido/Build/Intermediates/ADTCommercial.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ADTCommercial.build/Objects-normal/i386/KeychainItemWrapper.o
    /Users/rsangili/Desktop/Personal/iPhone-xcodeproj/AMPSmartClient/libAMPSmartClient.a(KeychainItemWrapper.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_KeychainItemWrapper.keychainItemData in:
    /Users/rsangili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ADTCommercial-cpvyllovxoojyngrlpxrjwdjxido/Build/Intermediates/ADTCommercial.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ADTCommercial.build/Objects-normal/i386/KeychainItemWrapper.o
    /Users/rsangili/Desktop/Personal/iPhone-xcodeproj/AMPSmartClient/libAMPSmartClient.a(KeychainItemWrapper.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_KeychainItemWrapper in:
    /Users/rsangili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ADTCommercial-cpvyllovxoojyngrlpxrjwdjxido/Build/Intermediates/ADTCommercial.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ADTCommercial.build/Objects-normal/i386/KeychainItemWrapper.o
    /Users/rsangili/Desktop/Personal/iPhone-xcodeproj/AMPSmartClient/libAMPSmartClient.a(KeychainItemWrapper.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_KeychainItemWrapper in:
    /Users/rsangili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ADTCommercial-cpvyllovxoojyngrlpxrjwdjxido/Build/Intermediates/ADTCommercial.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ADTCommercial.build/Objects-normal/i386/KeychainItemWrapper.o
    /Users/rsangili/Desktop/Personal/iPhone-xcodeproj/AMPSmartClient/libAMPSmartClient.a(KeychainItemWrapper.o)
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
```

Comment: try to remove `libAMPSmartClient.a`

Comment: under General Settings - Frameworks?

Comment: under General Settings - Frameworks? I tried, but it throws 60 errors